# Printing elements of a struct vector to file

Tags: c++, file, stdvector

I have a struct named `M_SP_NA_1`. The contents of this struct are as follows.

```
struct M_SP_NA_1 {
    uint8_t firstbyte = 0x01;
    uint8_t signalType;
    uint8_t cot;
    uint8_t asduLSB = 0x00;
    uint8_t asduMSB;
    uint8_t iot1 = 0x00;
    uint8_t iot2;
    uint8_t iot3 = 0x00;
    uint8_t valflag1 = 0x00;
    uint8_t valflag2;
};
```

And I have a vector defined like this. `std::vector<M_SP_NA_1> spSignals;` I `push_back` one `M_SP_NA_1` object into the `spSignals`vector.Now my vector named `spSignals` contains an element and the content of that element is as follows.

```
0x01 0x01 0x09 0x00 0x07 0x00 0x0b 0x00 0x00 0xd1
```

My aim is to write the content of the vector element named `spSignals`, whose content is as above, to the file named `signals.txt`.
First I tried the following method and got an error.

```
std::ofstream outputfile("signals.txt");
std::copy(spSignals.begin(), spSignals.end(),
std::ostream_iterator<uint8_t>(outputfile, "\n"));
```

Then i tried the below method and i didn't get an error

```
    std::ofstream outfile("C:\\Users\\*****\\Desktop\\signals.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
outfile.write((const char*)&spSignals[0], spSignals.size());
```

But this time I didn't get the output I wanted, instead it just printed `[]` to the file.
How can I print the content of my vector element to the file named `signals.txt` ?

Comment: Use text formatted output instead of outputting raw binary data using `write()`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I would appreciate if you provide a small code sample

Comment: Formatted in this sense `sprintf(buffer,"%02X ",onebyte);`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your data elements are in a `struct` and not in an iterable container. You cannot iterate over the elements in the `struct`

In your copy function, you will iterate over `M_SP_NA_1` types and not over `uint8_t`.

Therefore you will get an error. So you need to add an inserter function in your struct, something like:

```
friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const M_SP_NA_1& d) {
    return os << d.firstbyte << ' ' << d.signalType << ' ' << ...
}
```

Then put the correct type in the `std::ostream_iterator` (M_SP_NA_1). And then it will work.